# python simplify warning message

Tags: python, suppress-warnings

I'm getting this (three) runtime warnings, every time I run my code.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py:977: RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the additional knot would
coincide with an old one. Probable cause: s too small or too large
a weight to an inaccurate data point. (fp>s)
        kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=150,6 m=7499 fp=0.000001 s=0.000000
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py:977: RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the additional knot would
coincide with an old one. Probable cause: s too small or too large
a weight to an inaccurate data point. (fp>s)
        kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=150,6 m=7499 fp=0.000614 s=0.000000
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py:977: RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the additional knot would
coincide with an old one. Probable cause: s too small or too large
a weight to an inaccurate data point. (fp>s)
        kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=150,6 m=7499 fp=0.020861 s=0.000000
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
```

It looks like it's coming from some `scipy` function. Is there a way to catch the waring and instead print something like

```
RuntimeWarning: to see full warning comment out line 123
RuntimeWarning: to see full warning comment out line 123
RuntimeWarning: to see full warning comment out line 123
```

I know that I can use

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)
```

to ignore the warning completely, but I would still like to get the notification that there was a `RuntimeWarning`, just not the whole text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`warnings` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

> The printing of warning messages is done by calling `showwarning()`,
> which may be overridden; the default implementation of this function
> formats the message by calling `formatwarning()`, which is also
> available for use by custom implementations.

which mean you might assign own function to `warning.showwarning` if so desired, which is called as follows

```
warnings.showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None)
```

so if you want number of line only printed do standard ouptut then you might do

```
import warnings
def customshowwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    print("Warning in line", lineno)
warnings.showwarning = customshowwarning
warnings.warn("This text will not be printed")
```

output

```
Warning in line 5
```